# .on() event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure why the following code isn't working. If I change the `.on()` to `.live()` it works but live events hang around and since this is something will come on and off the page mmore than once, live will keep adding to the event line every time it's clicked. I guess the short and skinny is, why would this not fire?

```
$("#" + old_n).on('mousedown', function(evt) {
    console.log(old_n);

    if($(el).data('clickphase')) {
        return true;
    }

    $("#" + $.contextmenu).remove();
    $(el).data('served', true);

    if(typeof array_of_a[a_index][1] == 'function') {
        array_of_a[a_index][1](evt, el);
    }

    // console.log(array_of_a[a_index]);            
    // array_of_a[a_index][1](evt, el);
    $(el).removeData('served');
});
```

`old_n` is the id of the current `<li>` that's clicked on, which also has a `hover` event, but that shouldn't ruin the mousedown event right?

Comment: check if $("#" + old_n).length is > 0

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#" + old_n).on('mousedown', function(evt) {
```

Will only work if `old_n` is present when the page is rendered.  This is a directly bound event, identical to

```
$("#" + old_n).bind('mousedown', function(evt) {
```

You want a *delegated* event:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "#" + old_n, function(evt) {
```

This will cause all mousedown events anywhere in the document to be "listened to" by jQuery, and if any come from an element matching your selector—id of `old_n`—then the event handler will fire.

---

Of course, listening to every mousedown event anywhere in your document is a bit wasteful.  If you **know** that this element will only ever exist in, say, a div with an id of `foo` (and foo exists when the page is rendered), then why not just listen to events coming up to `foo`

```
$("#foo").on("mousedown", "#" + old_n, function(evt) {
```

Comment: So I changed it to... $("#contextmenu li").on('mousedown', "#" + old_n, function(evt) but that still won't fire off. The only way I can get it to fire is by either attaching to the document root or using a live call

Comment: Whatever you put in $() has to be present when the page renders.  So if #contextmenu isn't present when the page is rendered, that won't work

Comment: it isn't its a context menu that gets built on right click of an object. so the only way to bind an event to an element that isn't on the page when it gets rendered is with live or bind to document?

Comment: @Rob Or render the page with a div, and build your menu inside of *that*, and bind to that div.  Or just bind to the document.  That's what live is doing anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not a correct translation from [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on). Try this instead:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "#" + old_n, function (evt) {
    /*...*/
});
```

Comment: that still makes it bubble to the document root so when I use it, then use it again it fires it twice, and keeps building up like the live event

Comment: Does that mean you have multiple elements on the same page with the same `id`? If so, that's invalid HTML and you have to solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

`on` is not a drop in replacement for `live`. Try monitoring at the list item's `ul` level instead. This is more efficient and the benefit of `on`.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    //get clicked list item's id
    var id = $('this').prop('id');
});
```

Because you are monitoring at the `ul` level you will need to retrieve the information you want from the list item.